# Jitpack: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted

Tags: android, jitpack

I've googled, and some says it's fixed after few trys, and by creating a new release, but It doesn't seem to work for me.

How can I resolve this?

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':analytics'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
        platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
        build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
     To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
     Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

     Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
   > Cannot add task ':analytics:install' as a task with that name already exists.
   > Could not get unknown property 'androidJavadocs' for project ':analytics' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

https://jitpack.io/com/github/littlehome-eugene/analytics-android/1.0/build.log

Comment: Having the same problem here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have probably ran into: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123054726

As a workaround I installed it individually. i.e.

```
$ yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
$ yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, uhh spend a few hours until finally found a [solution](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/3687#issuecomment-455885806)

In short:

1. Create a private [gist](https://gist.github.com/) `android-sdk-license.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

cd $ANDROID_HOME
mkdir -p licenses

cat << EOF >> licenses/android-sdk-license
8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55
d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e
24333f8a63b6825ea9c5514f83c2829b004d1fee
EOF
```

2. Get a raw link to this file
3. Create `jitpack.yml` in the root of your project with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

before_install:
- curl PASTE_RAW_LINK_TO_GIST | sh
```

4. Commit & push

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you have the correct SDK Platform installed?

If not, go to Android Studio, then Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK. Select Android 8.1 with API Level 27 and install it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you get this error in Android Studio @Maxime Barber's suggestion should be the first thing you check. Calling `sdkmanager` from console could fail because it will probably use you system java instead Android Studio's bundled java.

Answer (score 0):

That fixed our CI build, adding yes | before installing system image, platform and build tools.

```
RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses

# update
RUN yes | sdkmanager --update

# Update SDK manager and install system image, platform and build tools
RUN yes | sdkmanager \
  "tools" \
  "platform-tools" \
  "extras;android;m2repository" \
  "extras;google;m2repository" \
  "extras;google;google_play_services" \
  "patcher;v4" \
  "build-tools;$ANDROID_TOOLS_VERSION" \
  "platforms;android-$ANDROID_BUILD_VERSION"

RUN sdkmanager --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall sdk can solve this error. On Android studio , go to Tool > SDK manager uninstall that sdk and install it again.

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of this error, **close android studio** and then run android studio again but this time, **run as administrator**