# "Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am getting this error in jitpack, I've tried everything on the internet. Below is my error

```
Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     platforms;android-26 Android SDK Platform 26
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
```

And when i run ./sdkmanager --licenses

```
 All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

Using sudo with the above command gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 5 more
```

additional error log

```
File /opt/android-sdk-linux/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not accepted.
```

I don't know why it's checking for licenses there when my sdk location is other

Comment: There seems to be a slightly mad [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54283093/608312), it may work though!

Comment: I had the same problem.  I downloaded the relevant SDKs via Android Studio, and at no point did it ask me about any licences.  Another unnecessary problem.

Comment: I "accepted" the licenses, but it must have not saved since the android sdk directory was read-only. Chmod 777-ing the sdk directory made things work for me. `sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/android-sdk`

Comment: @nathanfranke this is a good point - if the Android SDK directories are not writeable the licence acceptance doesn't stick. You can probably also get around that by running as the user that owns those folders, or is in a group ownership of the folders, depending on how the folders have been installed.

Comment: sudo chown  User -R /usr/lib/android-sdk

Comment: Much like some commenters above, when I ran into permission issues, I naturally used `sudo`, only to realize that after accepting the licenses, they still showed as not accepted under `user`. To solve this, precede the `sdkmanager --licenses` with `sudo chmod a+w $ANDROID_HOME`

Answer (score 612, accepted):

You need to accept the licences before building.

According to [Android SDK docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) you can use the following command depending on the sdkmanager location: Docs on `--licenses` option seems to be missing though.

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

GNU/Linux Distributions:

```
yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

macOS:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
yes | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Windows:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Flutter:

```
> flutter config --android-sdk 'path-of-android-sdk'(only for ubuntu user)
> flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: I got this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema`

Comment: @HendraWD If you have installed an extra Java in your computer(Note: Android Studio has it's own Java), You should make sure they have same version. Otherwise It may will occur this error. I solved it just now by setting "Android Studio/jre" path to JAVA_HOME.

Comment: For a Mac without Java installed, I had to `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`, `cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin`, `./sdkmanager --licenses`.

Comment: FWIW: It also seems like only JDK < 11 is supported, and funnily enough, Ubuntu 18.04 comes with `openjdk 11` as the default jdk. After making sure I was using a supported java version, I instead got `Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine`, and I found that I had to invoke `sdkmanager` using sudo.

Comment: I had to run the command with sudo in ubuntu,

yes | sudo ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

Comment: For newbies, %ANDROID_HOME% means the path where sdk is installed

Comment: on Windows hit `WIN+R` and execute the commande : 

`%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: @HendraWD this answer fixed the problem with the Xml error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210820/191463

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 inside Virtualbox , and latest Android studio 2022.1.1 Patch 1 "Electric Eel", With this specs, this is the path to sdkmanager:
*~/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin*

Answer (score 362):

In *Android Studio* go to **Tools -> SDK Manager**.

Go to **SDK Tools** tab.

Select the **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)** and download by pressing **Apply**.

[image]

On **Windows**, you can find the sdkmanager.bat at

**C:\Users\[your_user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin**

[image]

Comment: This is also what worked for me in OS X. The sdkmanager terminal option did not work.

Comment: This solution is working for Ubuntu V20.04

Comment: Works on Windows 10.

Comment: Best answer, works flawlessly on Win11 :)

Comment: yes! Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 - where other solution did not

Comment: Works on Arch Linux

Answer (score 91):

in Windows OS go to your sdkmanager path then execute

```
./sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

You can find your sdkmanager in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`

OR

For those people not using android studio on window os. Go to your cmdline-tools\tool\bin and type cmd on the directory box to open the directory in your terminal. Then run *sdkmanager --licenses*

To find your actual android SDK path follow the red marked area of the below picture

[image]

Comment: After this you can review each license and accept them accordingly through same bash window (Windows CMD throws an error. Use git bash or other instead of windows CMD)

Comment: I tried this and got a Java classdefnotfound error for some reason for XmlSchema.

Comment: Or copy "cmdline-tools" content to Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest folder and run [sdkmanager.bat --licenses] in Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin adress

Answer (score 56):

If you are working with Flutter then this command would definitely work for you.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: It ain't working. Don't say definitely when it's not definitely.

Answer (score 53):

## Problem: SDK license not accepted

[image]

#### Step 1: Open SDK Manager

After opening the SDK manager, open the SDK tools tab as shown below

[image]

#### Step 2: Check the option `Show Package Details`

It'll list out all the versions of SDK tools

[image]

#### Step 3: Install the required SDK tool version

Check the specific version of SDK tools that is complaining (for me, it was 29.0.3 as shown above in the first screenshot) from the list, accept the agreement in the dialog that opens next and you're done.

Comment: This solution worked well but some of the other solutions didn't work.

Comment: @NickN Glad that it helped you! :)

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH BRO. THIS ONE HAS WORKED ON WINDOWS. The code from a udacity tutorial was not working because of this issue and your solution has saved my day

Comment: @Dr.Mukama Welcome. :)

Comment: Also worked for me when others did not. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Apple Silicon

Comment: @PabloMiranda Wow! Great! :)

Comment: You are the best bro !!!

Comment: thanks man, worked fine here, using you solution

Answer (score 43):

### MacOS Catalina

#### Step 1: Changing Android Studio Preference

1. Open-up your Android Studio
2. Press **Command+,** or go to top-left AppBar **Android Studio > Preferences**.
3. From Left Pane, select **Appearance > System Settings > Android SDK**
4. Select **SDK Tools** next to **SDK Platforms** and under **Android SDK Location**
5. Check mark **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)** and Press **OK** button.
6. Wait for installation to be finished

[image: Locating Preferences of Android Studio]

[image: Android Studio Preferences]

#### Step 2 (For Flutter Users):

1. Go to Terminal and run the following command

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

#### Step 2 (For Android Users):

1. Go to the Terminal and run the following command

`export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

`yes | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: Perfect and very useful answer. Out of all the answers and different solutions I have tried, only this one worked well for me. I am using ionic and mac and the above solution was perfect and the detailed steps was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Steps 1 and 2 for flutter users worked for me. I'm currently using macOS Big Sur 11.6 and new to flutter and android studio setup all together. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 38):

You can accept the license agreements of the stated SDKs by going to the SDK Manager (Settings > [Search for Android SDK]) then find the packages noted in the error message and find them there. Chances are, you'll find SDKs that are not fully installed and installing them will ask you to accept the license agreement. [image]

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes a _lot_ more sense to be able to accept the licenses within AS than to mess about in command line. Worked a charm, should be at the top.

Comment: @dKen no problem. Thank you for appreciating it.

Comment: For me the SDK also needed to be updated, but to get my app to finally compile I also need to install the Android-SDK-Command-Line-Tools.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me:

`yes | ./sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"`

`yes | ./sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"`

`yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: Worked fine for me (Ubuntu 19.10, IntelliJ 2019.2.4). I just had to install openJDK because I had only the embedded JDK, not accessible from terminal `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 14):

use `android-28` with `build-tools` at version `28.0.3`; or `build-tools` at version `26.0.3`.

or try this: `yes | sudo sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: On windows you can just run `sdkmanager.bat --licenses` and type `y` for all the questions.

Comment: @Agung Santoso It's not that simple, it needs a greater explanation.

Answer (score 14):

For **Android Studio Arctic Fox**, it was solved for me by installing the **Google Play Licensing Library**.

1. Go to Preferences
2. Expand `Appearance & Behavior`
3. Then expand `System Settings`
4. Select `Android SDK` and go to `SDK Tools` tab
5. Install **Google Play Licensing Library**

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you are getting this error while using Flutter then please run the below command on command prompt.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

If you get below error after running the above command

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

Then please do the below steps

1. Open android studio
2. Go to SDK manager
3. Click on SDK tools tab
4. Install Android SDK command line tool
5. Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` again

Comment: That's Work for me

Comment: This is really helpfull

Answer (score 10):

In Android Studio go to: *Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools*

On the bottom right, check the "Show Package Details" box and download the version of sdk that you need:

[image: Android Studio Sdk Tools]

Answer (score 8):

Tried this on Android Studio and it worked for me:

Tools > SDK Manager (Make sure to check Show Packages below)

SDK Platforms > Show Packages > Android - 28
[image: SDK Platforms > Show Packages > Android - 28]

SDK Tools > Show Packages > 28.0.3
[image: SDK Tools > Show Packages > 28.0.3]

Answer (score 6):

Appears to be a bug at the momment: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123054726

Solution that worked for me:

Create a .travis.yml file in your project directory and copy these lines:

```
before_script:
- mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
- echo "24333f8a63b6825ea9c5514f83c2829b004d1fee" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
```

Reference: 
https://github.com/square/RxIdler/pull/18/files

Answer (score 6):

in Windows OS go to your sdkmanager path directory in cmd

You can find your sdkmanager in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin

then execute the followwing command:

**sdkmanager --licenses**

after that it will ask to accept license agreement several times then accept all by just typing **y** on cmd

Answer (score 5):

On **Ubuntu** it still didn't work using the answers suggested.

This is what worked for me:

cd `full-path-to-bin` folder, where `sdkmanager` is located.

```
yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root="full-path-to-bin"
```

In the option `--help` it shows we can pass common args to it, which finally accepted ALL licences:

```
Usage:
...
sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]
...
Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK containing this tool
```

Comment: This works. I did not want Android Studio so instead i downloaded the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools) , switched to the directory bin and ran the above command. It accepted all the licenses after

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in Windows 10:

```
C:
cd \Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin
sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

After, yes to all

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS 10.15.1, I got the same error even after accepted all the licenses by running `sdkmanager --licenses` It worked after I updated the ANDROID_HOME path configuration in the ~/.bash_profile to the following

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/your_username/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

And reload the ~/.bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried many solutions but didn't work for me.
The below solution works for me.

locate the sdkmanager file in android SDK.

In my case :
~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin

go to that path : `cd  ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin`

Accept licenses manually : `./sdkmanager --licenses`
Enter Yes or y

Answer (score 2):

If you are using flutter go with the following steps

```
1.open the command prompt
```

Then the following command

```
2.C:\Users\niroshan>flutter doctor
```

And you will see the issues as follows

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1339], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    X Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Actually what you have to run is the below command

```
C:\Users\niroshan>flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g789PvvW4qo really helped me. What had done is open SDK Manager and download any new SDK Platform (dont worry it wont affect your desired api level).

Because with downlaoding any SDK Platforms(API level), you should accept licences. That's the trick worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when trying to run an app on my android device in a different project where I was working with some old version of tomcat8 and had to set the JAVA_OPTS variable and value. So I removed this system variable for JAVA_OPTS, which had a Variable value set to -Xms1024m (Remove the JAVA_OPTS system variable, but you can also store it for future use if you need to revert to using your old projects that might need it).

Then run the SDK manager bat file in your sdk path:
PS C:\Users[your_pc_username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin> .\sdkmanager.bat --licenses

Accept all licenses (Y).

Answer (score 2):

How I solve this problem (AndroidStudio 4.2)

- Click in `Build` tab
- Select `Failed to install the following Android SDK packages ...` (warning)
- Click **Install missing SDK package(s)**

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers, you can also change to the sdkmanager directory and in a sub shell and accept the licenses there

```
(
    cd /home/user/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin
    yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just done File -> Invalidate caches and restart 
Then install missing packages.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

1. Add USER Environment variables:

NOTE: Path should be appended

```
JAVA_HOME           %ProgramFiles%\Android\Android Studio\jre
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT    %LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk
Path                %LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk
```

2. Run the below command to accept licenses:

NOTE: Accept all licenses (say `y`)

```
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

3. Now run your app:

(like below, or another command that failed for you):

```
cd \myapp\
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case I just installed a new version of android studio on a new laptop and cloned the old repository where
`buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"` at application level build.gradle.
I just upgraded to `30.0.3` which **android studio recommended** on its own and the problem went away

Answer (score 1):

I moved my Sdks and Avds folder as it was using lots of memory in local disk c, but after that I got the above issue.

For me Invalidate Caches/Restart solve the issue

File->Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

In my case updating **buildToolsVersion** in app level build.gradle worked perfectly. If you don't know which to use you can create new project and copy buildToolsVersion from that into existing one.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner solution with downgrade to java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y && export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 && flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

Just visit to the Build.gradle(Module Appname.app)
here, find the "buildToolsVersion" and change the version to "32.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, make sure that the accepted licenses are in the correct location.
After accepting them with `./sdkmanager --licenses` I had to copy them to the licenses directory directly under android-sdk with:

`cp /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/licenses/* /usr/lib/android-sdk/li censes`