# Can't access "sdkmanager" in the Command Prompt

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, sdk

I'm starting to learn JavaScript and React Native (but like REALLY starting). I'm following a course on Udemy and I got stuck on a part where I need to accept some licenses using the "sdkmanager --licenses" command line on the cmd. Cmd tells me that "sdk manager path not recognized as an internal or external command". I tried moving on with the course, but a few steps later, cmd printed this:

> "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted."

I looked for some answers online, but couldn't fix it. I tried some things related to Environment Variables and some things saying the path of the sdkmanager shouldn't conatain white spaces or non ascii characters, but it didn't fixed.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Thanksssss!

PS: I just reseted my computer and followed every step, installed Node.js, JDK, Android Studio, VSCode and all the things the course asked me to.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. nice job learning . It is very common to have such issues. Some may get issues for others things work seamlessly. it depends on what your admin rights are on your PC etc. I suggest trying another tutorial for any step missed in Udemy course. Always use search as well before posting, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not-b  should help as well
or try google as well. I saw lots of threads on other websites.

Comment: Turns out some tools of the SDK were disabled in the Android Studio itself. Downloaded them and all works fine now! Thanks :)