# Ionic cordova build android error : Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am a beginner. I can type a little english.
I try to build ionic app. but error

[error detail img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTcs.jpg)

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
```

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools')
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3 in C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4
> build-tools;29.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3
> emulator Android Emulator
> platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
> tools Android SDK Tools
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\el_fe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\myapp_63\BBPHApp63\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\myapp_63\BBPHApp63\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not)

Comment: Accept Licenses for Android SDK.