# I am using VS Code for Flutter. I have downloaded Android SDK platform 30. But it tells me to download 29 version

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am new to flutter. Here is a list of available tools on SDK Manager -
[image: List of tools installed]

As you can see I've downloaded the tools. But debugging in the ide shows an error and tells me download a tools that are not installed -

'''

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   > Failed to install the following SDK components:
      build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
      platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
    Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
   2

   * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log 
   output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

   BUILD FAILED in 51s
   [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
   Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
   Exited (sigterm)
```

'''

Please help me out.

Comment: Not sure about that, but it could probably be licenses issue. Try to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` from command line. Type `y` and press enter to accept licenses if they are not accepted.

Comment: This happened for me once.. i restared VSCODE and next time it started in the emulator. I just installed android studio and the command line tools.. maybe it was an enviroment issue

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be errors in installing certain dependencies ( sdk 30 ). Might be a technical glitch. Try installing again using flutter doctor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to accept the licenses before building.

Try this command in the terminal

```
 flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Try flutter doctor command in your terminal. which helps us diagnose issues with your setup

```
flutter doctor
```

to learn more https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641042/7904389

Answer (score 0):

Please share the `android/app/build.gradle`, it is probably targeting API level 29 (`targetSdkVersion 29` and `compileSdkVersion 29`). Change them to `30` **or** download the API level 29 SDKs.

If it still doesn't work after that, the SDK might be missing, go to the `ANDROID_HOME` directory and ensure it contains an `sdk` directory with the stuff you want.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what the error was, but creating a new project worked for me.