# Android Studio first install and default setup. "Build your first app" guide fails on first run

Tags: android, android-studio

The Guide: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp

I haven't done anything to the project. I installed it using all defaults as stated in the guide, and have followed the guide itself.

Earlier, the project failed on a package permission. It was solved by this SE post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61480578

Based on my hunt, it seems that my manifest is missing the critical information, but I don't know what it's missing, what it's supposed to look like, syntax, nothing. . . I mean this is my first run of any of it.

Here is the message:

```
07/28 15:39:56: Launching 'app' on [device REDACTED].
Install successfully finished in 406 ms.
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication" />

</manifest>
```

### The Question is:

What exactly do I need to add to this, and where do I need to add it, to make the run work?

Comment: You have not described the problem in enough detail. What does "fails" mean, specifically? Is the build failing? If so, what build errors are you getting? Or, is the build fine, but then the app is crashing when it runs? If so, what are you seeing in Logcat? Beyond that, what is your environment (Android Studio version, development OS and version, Android OS version, etc.)?

Comment: @CommonsWare failure message added. Thanks.

Comment: Your project appears to be missing an `<activity>` element and possibly the entire activity. Perhaps you accidentally chose "No Activity" rather than "Empty Activity" in the new project wizard.

Comment: Much of the linked basic tutorial text does not match what's on the screen, and I had to take my best guess. Here is the page in question: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project, and a pic of the screen that was presented: https://imgur.com/xPrQR98 . What should the tutorial have said to choose?

Comment: It's been a day . . . there's "Empty Activity" buried. I'll restart with that.

Comment: The documentation often lags behind. The screenshots that I saw there are from 4.1.1, and you should be either on 4.2.x or Arctic Fox (which went stable today). And I have no clue why "No Activity" is the first option for a first-time developer. Anyway, I wish you better luck with a fresh project!

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. And thanks for being one of the good guys on SE!