# Android with github action some licences have not been accepted

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, github-actions

I setuped the following github workflow to build an aab

```
name: upload-aab-to-play-console
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main-kt-prod
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        id: Setup_JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
  - name: build-with-gradle
    id: build
    run: |
      chmod +x gradlew
      ./gradlew build
```

But I get the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 32-rc1 not accepted.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;32.0.0-rc1 Android SDK Build-Tools 32-rc1
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
  Using Android SDK: /usr/local/lib/android/sdk
```

I tried this line `yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`
from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641042/15262615) right before `./gradlew build` but I got no such file or directory error

Comment: please show the exact command you ran when you tried to accept the license along with the error message.

Comment: @rethab i updated the question

Comment: do you really need your slack webhook url there?

Comment: For the rest of the workflow yes and it works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before the gradle build step, you probably want to use the [setup-android](https://github.com/android-actions/setup-android) action, because it:

- downloads the SDK commandline tools
- accepts the SDK licenses

You can add it like so:

```yaml
- name: Setup Android SDK
  uses: android-actions/setup-android@v2
```