# Unable to compile Flutter demo script in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am new to app development and started learning `Flutter`. But when I try to run the default dummy script in `Nexux 6` Virtual Phone, it gives me error and quits! Here is the code:

````
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in C:\Users\Raghaw Panpaliya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
      > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
           build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
        To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
        Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

        Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Raghaw Panpaliya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```
````

Comment: run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and see where is gets and [How to resolve license issues in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not) might help

Comment: I ran that command in `CMD` as well as `flutter_console` , but I got this result:

Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Open SDK manager:**

[image: img]

then select **Android Sdk Command-line Tools**
**Note: If it's already checked then**

- Uncheck
- Apply
- Re-check
- Apply

[image: img]

Alternatively in Android Studio for Windows:

Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Appearance & Behaviour` -> `System Settings` -> `Android SDK` -> `SDK Tools` -> check `Google Play Licensing Library` -> check `Android SDK Platform-Tools` -> check `Android SDK Command-line-Tools(latest)` -> Click `Apply`, and then `Ok`

After the installation, build your application. It should work. check the status running `flutter doctor` from command line