# Flutter Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac', missing build tools even if installed

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm trying to run a simple new Flutter project after following the steps from the flutter website, the flutter doctor saying everything is ok except some missing compoment from visual studio c++ but i'm using android studio which is ok.
But when i run the project on android emulator i have this error.
As you can see I think i have those tools installed already. Also i've tried cleaning and rebuilding and deleting the `.gradle` folder in my users directory but it gives the same error.

[image]

```
   Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
   Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
   Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Program Files 
   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses
   License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
   Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
   Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
   Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 31 in C:\Program Files 
   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses
   License for package Android SDK Platform 31 accepted.
   Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)".
   Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   > Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-31 Android SDK Platform 31
      build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
   Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.


   * Try:
   > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
   > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
   > Run with --scan to get full insights.

   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

   BUILD FAILED in 2m 29s
   Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you install the Android SDK Command lines tools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not)

Comment: @jraufeisen yes the latest version 8.0