# 3 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. on macbook (intel)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm new to flutter and I ran into a problem.

> 3 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted

I looked at the solution through a folder that I don't have, namely, through `/usr/local/share/android-sdk`. I have a macbook on an intel processor, does anyone know the solution?

to be honest, I tried to find this folder and thought that but I can't, I don't know how to solve this , I need help

Comment: Could you please post the logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not)

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Accept everything by clicking `y`