Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted in Kotlin
I'm stuck with my Kotlin Android project. I'm trying to run it but it says:

Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
platforms;android-34 Android SDK Platform 34
build-tools;34.0.0 Android SDK Build-Tools 34
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
All licenses can be accepted using the sdkmanager command line tool:
sdkmanager.bat --licenses
Or, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle
Using Android SDK: /home/javierac/Documents/tfg/camera_app

I have the next configuration in Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager:

and have tried activating those which API Level is 34.
I have also tried: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licenses-have-not-been-accepted-error-in-android-studio/ and https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update?hl=es-419#download-with-gradle, but I haven't been able to solve it.
I'm using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition.
Any help is greatful!

Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not

@tyczj yes, but i don't have that folder/file in my computer. And I neither have sdkmanager installed through the command line.
